# Generate JSON is never the same

Tags: javascript

I don't understand when I launch the script. My JSON is never the same...
I try to change the time of my Timeout but same problem

```
//   Call the file functions.js
var functions = require('./functions.js')

/* 
Function getAllIssueForSCII displays all the issues in the form of a JSON and that browses all the keys that are in the SCII project
Function pushInitialization initializes the computer score card to 80 on Jira

*/

functions.getAllIssueForSCII().then(function(json){
    for (let i=0; i<50;i++){      
        console.log(json.issues[i].key);


        /* 
        A delay is added so that Jira can correctly recover the value 80.
        Thanks to this value, we can do all the calculation  (Function calculate)  
        Function pushComputerScoreCard  push the final value into the computer score card.
        Function generateJSON generates a JSON.
        Function replaceCharacter solve the problem of array inside the JSON 
        */

        setTimeout(function() {

            functions.calculate(json.issues[i]);
            functions.generateJSON(json.issues[i].key);
            functions.replaceCharacter();


        }, 1000)
    }
});
```

Function getAllIssueForSCII()

```
function getAllIssueForSCII(){
    var options = {
        method: 'GET',
        url: 'https://***.atlassian.net/rest/api/3/search?jql=project=SCII+AND+issuetype=Story+AND+resolution=Unresolved+AND+status%20in("In%20Review","In%20Inspection","Inspected","Inspection%20Needed","Feedback")',
        headers: {  
            'Accept': 'application/json',
            'Authorization': "Basic ***"
        }
    };


    return new Promise(function (resolve) {
        request(options, function (error, response, data) {
            if (!error && response.statusCode === 200) {
                console.log('JIRA login success!!')
                var json = JSON.parse(data);
                console.log("Filtered Issues: ", { issues: json.issues.filter(issue => issue.expand.key) });
                resolve(json);            
            } else {
            }

        })
    })
}
```

Function calculate() it's only some calcul

Function generateJson()

```
function generateJSON(key){
    var table = []


    table.push({"executionDate":dateTime,
    "issueID":key,
    "priority":{
        "jira": priority, 
        "computed":score1
    },
    "expectedValue":{
        "jira": expected, 
        "computed":score2
    },
    "customerCr":{  
        "jira":customer,
        "computed":score3
    },
    "effortEstimate":{  
        "jira":effort_estimate,
        "computed":score4
    },
    "pmWeight":{  
        "jira":pm_weight,
        "computed":score5
    },
    "netRevenue":{  
        "jira":net_revenue,
        "computed":score6
    },
    "scoreCard":{  
        "original":score_card,
        "computed":total
    }
})

var json = JSON.stringify(table,null, 2);

fs.appendFile('templateLog.json', json, 'utf8', function (err) {
    if (err) console.error(err)

});

}
```

Function replaceCharacter (replace ][ by ,)

```
function replaceCharacter(){
    const options = {
        files: 'templateLog.json',
        from: /]\[/g,
            to: ',',
        };

        replace(options, (error, results) => {
            if (error) {
                return console.error('Error occurred:', error);
            }
            console.log('Replacement results:', results);
        });
    }
```

Actual result:

- 1rt launch: get 1641 element
- 2nd launh : get 947 element and the last element finish like that:

  ```
    {
    "executionDate": "13-6-2019",
    "issueID": "SCII-56",
    "priority": {
      "jira": "Highest",
      "computed": 25
    },
    "expectedValue": {
      "jira": "High",
      "computed": 25
    },
    "customerCr": {
      "jira": "No",
      "computed": 0
    },
    "effortEstima
  ```

Expected result:

- 1rt launch: get 1641 element
- 2nd launch: get 1641 element
- and same and same

Thanks for your help

Comment: You probably need to post the code for: calculate, pushComputerScoreCard (where is this used?), generateJSON, and replaceCharacter

Comment: Yeah they are in another file, in this file i'm only call the function

Comment: Well, the code shown has references to functions that change the JSON, so it would be handy to know how they change it. Just a for loop showing 3 function calls for each thing does not say anything about what's happening, only that it's happening 50 times. :) First remark would be,having to introduce delays on async things to get stuff usually is a sign of bigger issues.

Comment: Is the JSON getting truncated 'on the wire' or is it your Javascript code that is truncating it?

Comment: @Shilly Ok i'm trying to understand what you explain me but so, what do you advise me to do ?

Comment: @MikeBrockington it' s the JSON

Comment: Ok I thing I find my problem ... it's my function replacecharacter. I'm trying to change ][ by , when i'm adding element in my json
And i'm using a special library for change character by anothr

Comment: Add the code for `getAllIssueForSCII()`, `calculate()`, `generateJSON()`, `replaceCharacter()` and any functions called by those. We need to see what you are doing to the json string before we can try to understand why your json string changes incorrectly. I'm just saying that since you use promises, ( the `.then()` chain ) and promises are exactly made to sync async stuff, there should be no need for setTimeouts. So if your code has need for setTimeouts in various places to make it work, there's probably a synchronisation issue that will affect your json.

Comment: @Shilly I add the script of different function, thanks for your help :)

Comment: Why are you trying to work with a timeout instead of another promise resolution step?

Comment: @connexo In fact, i'm pushing a value into a platform, so when I push all value, in this moment I can launch the different function so it's why I put my timeout :/ maybe what i'm doing i's wrong ...

Comment: I hide my function replaceCharacter and everything work ... so i think the problem come with this function :/

Comment: 1) I don't understand what `replaceCharacter()` is supposed to do. It looks alot like after you created a new json log file, you try to update that files text again inside the `replaceCharacter()`? Is the `setTimeout()` needed because you fs.readFile() again inside the `replace()` function? If so, why not do these updates before creating the file?

Comment: 2) And why the for loop with 50 iterations? How do you know jira will return exactly 50 records every time? It looks a bit that you have global variables `priority`, `expected`, `customer` etc that you calculate inside `calculate()`, but use as globals instead of passing them as parameters to `generateJSON()` as you do with the key. If not, where are all these variables defined?